# Has facebook started rejecting individual developers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

My app integrates the facebook login function. After receiving the facebook notification, business verification must be performed, otherwise access will be denied. I looked at the relevant instructions. Starting from February 1 this year, new applications will be required to undergo commercial verification. Starting from May 1, old applications will also be required to undergo commercial verification. Those who have not been notified are only temporary, and the scope is being gradually expanded.

Will there be no way for individual developers to integrate facebook into the app to quickly log in in the future? Why does facebook do this?

Comment: We can only speculate why they do this, but I think the main reason is "accountability", and their attempt to better protect user data from abuse by 3rd parties. Saying "No, we don't want you on our platform any more" is easier towards a tangible entity like a company, than a personal user account (which can easily be set up with fake data, meaning abusive developers could easily create new ones, in an attempt to provide the same bad functionality again with a new app.)

Comment: @CBroe I just want to implement facebook quick login in my own app, get the basic avatar, nickname, and at most an email. Facebook should allow Standard access to limited information instead of requiring business verification for everyone.

Comment: _"Facebook should allow [...]"_ - other than giving you that Big Lebowski quote about opinions :-), I don't know what we could do with that, here. You'd have to take the issue up with Facebook, and convince them ...

Comment: @CBroe I submit a question in its  developer community. They don't reply.